# How do I find elements in this hpricot object?

Tags: ruby, hpricot, amazon-product-api

Given the hpricot xml at the bottom of this post, how would I select the "item" without having to use .each? Every single piece of documentation uses a variation of

```
@res.items.each do |item|
  # do stuff
end
```

Which is pointless in this case because there is only ever one "item". Been tearing y hair out for the last ages trying to get this right.

**Edited to add more information:**

Ok so judging from the early comments, I'm missing the point somewhere so I'll provide more information.

I'm using a ruby gem called [amazon-ecs](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/projects/amazon-ecs) to retrieve product information from Amazon. On the gem's site it is described as

> A generic Ruby Amazon Product Advertising API (previously known as E-commerce REST API) using Hpricot. It uses Response and Element wrapper classes for easy access to the REST API XML output. It is generic, so you can extend Amazon::Ecs to support the other not-implemented operations easily; and the response object just wraps around Hpricot element object, instead of providing one-to-one object/attributes to XML elements map.

Now to be hones I don't really understand what that means but I suspect the bit about the wrapping Response object is what's making this difficult!

Basically, when I do this:

```
@res = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(ean, options_hash)
```

and then I print out "debug @res", I get what I have below.

Hope that helps!
**End edit**

**Hpricot xml:**

```
<Amazon::Ecs::Response:0xa4449cc @doc=#<Hpricot::Doc 
{xmldecl "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>"} 
{elem <itemlookupresponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05"> 
  {elem <operationrequest> 
    {elem <httpheaders> 
      {emptyelem <header name="UserAgent" value="Ruby">} 
    </HTTPHeaders>} 
    {elem <requestid> "b89bad91-f5a1-4daf-87f2-d309dded35d6" </RequestId>} 
    {elem <arguments> 
      {emptyelem <argument name="Operation" value="ItemLookup">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="SearchIndex" value="Books">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="Signature" value="dasdasdsadsadsafdfdsfsdsasadsadsd">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="ItemId" value="9780307463746">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="IdType" value="ISBN">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="sdasdsadsadsadsadsadd">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="Timestamp" value="2011-02-17T15:08:09Z">} 
      {emptyelem <argument name="Service" value="AWSECommerceService">} 
    </Arguments>} 
    {elem <requestprocessingtime> "0.0252220000000000" </RequestProcessingTime>} 
  </OperationRequest>} 
  {elem <items> 
    {elem <request> 
      {elem <isvalid> "True" </IsValid>} 
      {elem <itemlookuprequest> 
        {elem <condition> "New" </Condition>} 
        {elem <deliverymethod> "Ship" </DeliveryMethod>} 
        {elem <idtype> "ISBN" </IdType>} 
        {elem <merchantid> "Amazon" </MerchantId>} 
        {elem <offerpage> "1" </OfferPage>} 
        {elem <itemid> "9780307463746" </ItemId>} 
        {elem <responsegroup> "Small" </ResponseGroup>} 
        {elem <reviewpage> "1" </ReviewPage>} 
        {elem <searchindex> "Books" </SearchIndex>} 
      </ItemLookupRequest>} 
    </Request>} 
    {elem <item> 
      {elem <asin> "0307463745" </ASIN>} 
      {elem <detailpageurl> "http://www.amazon.com/Rework-Jason-Fried/dp/0307463745%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIV6GP6CJC3AINUUQ%26tag%3Dws%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0307463745" </DetailPageURL>} 
      {elem <smallimage> 
        {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL._SL75_.jpg" </URL>} 
        {elem <height units="pixels"> "75" </Height>} 
        {elem <width units="pixels"> "50" </Width>} 
      </SmallImage>} 
      {elem <mediumimage> 
        {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL._SL160_.jpg" </URL>} 
        {elem <height units="pixels"> "160" </Height>} 
        {elem <width units="pixels"> "106" </Width>} 
      </MediumImage>} {elem <largeimage> {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL.jpg" </URL>} {elem <height units="pixels"> "500" </Height>} {elem <width units="pixels"> "331" </Width>} </LargeImage>} {elem <imagesets> {elem <imageset category="primary"> {elem <swatchimage> {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL._SL30_.jpg" </URL>} {elem <height units="pixels"> "30" </Height>} {elem <width units="pixels"> "20" </Width>} </SwatchImage>} {elem <smallimage> {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL._SL75_.jpg" </URL>} {elem <height units="pixels"> "75" </Height>} {elem <width units="pixels"> "50" </Width>} </SmallImage>} {elem <mediumimage> {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL._SL160_.jpg" </URL>} {elem <height units="pixels"> "160" </Height>} {elem <width units="pixels"> "106" </Width>} </MediumImage>} {elem <largeimage> {elem <url> "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Qz6afdrLL.jpg" </URL>} {elem <height units="pixels"> "500" </Height>} {elem <width units="pixels"> "331" </Width>} </LargeImage>} </ImageSet>} </ImageSets>}
      {elem <itemattributes> 
        {elem <author> "Jason Fried" </Author>} 
        {elem <author> "David Heinemeier Hansson" </Author>} 
        {elem <manufacturer> "Crown Business" </Manufacturer>} 
        {elem <productgroup> "Book" </ProductGroup>} 
        {elem <title> "Rework" </Title>} 
      </ItemAttributes>} 
    </Item>} 
  </Items>} 
</ItemLookupResponse>}
```

Comment: That's not an XML document. It's a printed Hpricot object. Are you trying to parse this mess verbatim or are you recreating the Hpricot object first?

Comment: Ok it seems I'm pretty lost with what I'm doing here so I edited the OP to try and provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, extract the Hpricot object from @res (from the [docs](http://amazon-ecs.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Amazon/Ecs/Response.html)).

```
doc = @res.doc
```

Then, you should be able to use the Hpricot object:

```
puts (doc/:item).inner_html
```

Comment: Perfect. That's the bit that was messing me up. Thanks a million.

Comment: It's gas but now that I understand what's going on and I've read the docs you linked me to, I've realized I'm better off not extracting the Hpricot object at all! Slightly ironic! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

`item = (doc/:header).first`

The above should get you the first `header` node in the XML document. Its not tested so I would give it some testing

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too but I get a NoMethodError: "undefined method `/' for #<Amazon::Ecs::Response:0xade2e84>", I guess because it's wrapped in an Amazon response or something?

Comment: I never get to see any raw xml, basically I'm using a third party class whose method just returns what I have above. I edited the OP to provide more info though.